# d3.js: suggested node position in force layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I would like to create a graph where nodes have suggested positions, but I would also like to use the force layout to ensure the nodes themselves don't overlap. Is this possible in d3?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by:

- Disabling the default gravity and charge forces.
- Implementing [collision detection](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/collision.html).
- Implementing "custom" gravity that attracts each node to its suggested position.

Here's a live example:

- http://bl.ocks.org/1804919

Similar techniques were used in [Shan Carter's visualization of Obama's 2013 budget proposal](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/02/13/us/politics/2013-budget-proposal-graphic.html), which are further discussed in a [tutorial by Jim Vallandingham](http://vallandingham.me/bubble_charts_in_d3.html).

Comment: Perfect!  If there was a most helpful developer award, you would win it :)