# Algorithm to draw connections between nodes without overlapping nodes

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph

I have a series of nodes in a graph. The nodes are placed by the user in specific spots. The nodes are guaranteed to not overlap and, in fact, to have a buffer of space between them. These nodes are connected and each edge joins to a node at a specific point. I need to draw the edges between the nodes such that the edges:

- (required) do not overlap the parent nodes
- (ideally) would not overlap any node

I am not worried about edge crossings. Bonus points if there's an implementation of this in Javascript. I am unable to use any libraries outside of Javascript.

Comment: Take a look at d3.js force directed graph layout: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html. I think also that this SO answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397961/d3-js-suggested-node-position-in-force-layout

Comment: From the discussion of overlapping, I assume this is not a graph in the graph theory sense, with dimensionless nodes. Could you give e.g. a link to the rules for your graph?

Comment: The nodes are already placed, so any algorithm that rearranges the nodes is not helpful. I'm looking specifically for how to draw the edges without moving the nodes.http://

Comment: What do you mean parent nodes? The nodes you are drawing edges between? If you draw an edge from A to B, then it is going to intersect both A and B by definition, no?

Comment: Does this mean that you do not always want straight edges?

Comment: Felix - correct. I'd like to minimize bends, but that's not as important.

Comment: By 'unable to use and libraries outside of javascript' do you mean you have to implement this in pure javascript? Meaning no jquery or  graph library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be using [**Bézier Curves**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve):

> "A Bézier curve is defined by a set of control points P0 through Pn,
>   where n is called its order (n = 1 for linear, 2 for quadratic, etc.).
>   **The first and last control points are always the end points** of the
>   curve; however, **the intermediate control points (if any) generally do
>   not lie on the curve**."

So the basic idea is to use parent node(s) as intermediate control points. You may also use points of the edges as intermediate control points to avoid edges overlapping.

In the wiki article you can find nice [animations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Constructing_B.C3.A9zier_curves) explaining it.

For **javascript implementation** I took a look at the followings libs:

- [jsdraw2d](http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/) (LGPL license) with a [nice demo](http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/demo/curvesbezier.htm) and well referenced. Implemented it also using *HTML5 and SVG* for performance ([jsdraw2dX](http://jsdraw2dx.jsfiction.com/)).
- [jsbezier](http://code.google.com/p/jsbezier/) on google code

But if you google *"javascript bezier library"* you can find more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with C# and .NET you can explore Microsoft.GLEE library (description is [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/f1303e46-965f-401a-87c3-34e1331d32c5/default.aspx) and [here](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64284/gd2007-glee.pdf)) via ILSpy, or even theoretically save this sources to .csproj, modify and recompile it with [Script#](http://scriptsharp.com/) to JavaScript.