# D3 show text for nodes when zoomed

Tags: d3.js, zooming, overlap

The number of nodes in my d3 graph is too large. So I built a zoom mechanism in that graph. Now the problem is, I just cannot display text for each nodes since they will overlap each other. However when I zoom in to the nodes, the space is enough to display texts.

[image]

So how do I show texts when the space is enough to show all of them without overlapping?

Comment: You'll have to move the labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this same problem in the past. Unfortunately optimal label placement is not an easy problem. To mitigate overlap effects one option is to use a [restricted force layout for label placement](http://bl.ocks.org/MoritzStefaner/1377729). You can also try using callouts to allow the labels to move farther away from the nodes.

In the past I have implemented a sort of greedy collision detection based algorithm that goes something like:

```
sort the labels in decreasing priority
for each label in the list // so most important first
    if the label does not overlap any placed labels
        place the label and add it to my collision data structure (e.g. quad tree)
    else
        hide the label
```

Obviously this will have some non-optimal cases and it can be slow if you have a lot of animations going on. But when you have the option to zoom in to see more label and if your absolute number of labels is not too high then it works quite well. There are also a number of obvious ways to speed it up like restricting testing to only labels within the view (but then you need to update on pan).

You may find some helpful suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397961/d3-js-suggested-node-position-in-force-layout) including an implementation of [collision detection](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1804919).